# How to display URL in status message?

Tags: forms

I want to customize the status message after creating a content to include the current URL.

From

> @type %title has been updated.

to

> @type %title has been updated. Your permalink is (URL)

I'm running Drupal 7 using the String Overrides module.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to create the message yourself, since the url is not available as a parameter in the string, like the type and title is via `@type` and `%title`.

To do this, you can add a custom submit function with `hook_form_alter` and delete the message created by the node module. This would look like this:

```
module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (strpos($form_id, 'node_form') !== FALSE) {
    $form['#submit'][] 'my_custom_submit_handler';
  }
}

function my_custom_submit_handler(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Unset previous set messages.
  drupal_get_messages('status');
  drupal_set_message(t('Your custom string', array('@with' => 'params')));
}
```

Comment: Great answer, this is very useful. The only flaw I see is that `drupal_get_messages` would remove any other status messages that is in the queue.

Comment: @corbacho That's true, this is a simple solution that will cover 99% of the needs. It is possible that this solution will remove other modules's messages set. This can be fixed be tweaking the module weight to make sure that it adds the custom submit handler before other modules. But this is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: true. btw, I'm subscribed to this. http://drupal.org/node/127262 Hopefully we have a decent way of altering messages for Drupal 8

Comment: Could You help me, as well? My code `function mymod_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if (strpos($form_id, 'node_form') !== FALSE) {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'mymod_nodes_add_message';
  }
}

function mymod_add_message(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $message = t("Thank you for updating %nodetype", array('%nodetype' => $form['type']['#value']));
  drupal_get_messages('status');
  drupal_set_message($message);
}` results in both my and standard ".. has been updated." message. Mine comes first. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Add your own submit function to node form (see http://goo.gl/FJO0s for details), and inside update the message already set by node_form_submit() to your liking.